# Downloading multiple files with data-downloadurl

Tags: javascript, html, file, drag-and-drop

I was looking over this case study on HTML5 drag-and-drop file download using data-downloadurl. I have a working model of this method that can download a file retrieved from the server on drop, but I am wondering if there is a way to set the data-downloadurl to download multiple files at once.

What I was thinking is something like a comma-separated list of urls like:

`data-downloadurl="{$item.mime}:{$item.name}:{$item.url},
       {$item2.mime}:{item2.name"}:{item2.url}`

but I know this doesn't work..is there any way to do this?

Comment: I see that you haven't had a lot of action on this question.  Have you come to a conclusion on this?  If you have, come back and update this.  I'm on the search for the answer to this one.