# chrome dragout multiple files using dragstart event.dataTransfer

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, blob

I currently have an app which generates some content in javascript, converts it to a blob, and then allows the user to drag it out onto their desktop to save it as a file.  The key line looks like this:

```
 event.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL",
                  'application/octet-stream:' + desiredFilename + ':' + blobURL);
```

This works fine in Chrome as it is, but ideally I'd like the user to be able to drag out multiple files simultaneously.

- I see that Firefox has a [mozSetDataAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#setData.28.29) method which I guess is their way of exposing this functionality, but I can't find anything equivalent in Chrome.
- I've tried playing with `dataTransfer.items.add` which does seem to do something to the `dataTransfer` object but it doesn't produce a working drag, even when used for a single file.
- I've tried providing an array as the second argument to `setData` above, which works for one item, but not for more.
- I've tried calling `setData` multiple times, to see if each call adds the additional data, but sadly it just overwrites the original data.
- I wonder whether there is some way of specifying a single downloadurl with some kind of multipart type, that will allow me to specify multiple blobs and their desired file names. See [this unanswered SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10605043/2399799) which more or less asks this question.
- I also wondered whether there was some way of creating a `FileList` or `DataTransferItemList` and assigning them to the event somehow, but there doesn't seem to be any way of creating instances of these classes from scratch.

Really I only care about Chrome, though FF and IE are possibly of interest.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for a solution to this, any ideas?

Comment: this seems to be impossible in 2021 as well